# O método que envia e-mail funciona, mas como evitar que a quantidade de emails recebidos virem spam?

Tags: java, android, smtp, gmail, spam

Tenho um método que envia e-mail em back ground que funciona bem, mas preciso arrumar um jeito de que conforme a quantidade de emails recebidos não virem Spam.
Já pesquisei sobre o framework JMS(Java Message Service) mas não descobri um jeito de fazer isso funcionar e não encontrei um exemplo.

A ideia é chamar esse frame work e passar o SMTP dentro dele.

Se puderem mostrar um exemplo ficarei agradecido.

Lembrando que o método funciona bem, mas e se no caso um e-mail receber mais de 10 mil emails por exemplo, poderia ir para o Spam. Por isso queria achar uma forma de isso não acontecer.

Segue abaixo o método que utilizo para enviar o email em back ground:

```
ui.btnEnviarPedidoParaEmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                rec = "";
                subject = "Pedido Solicitado";
                textMessage = "Nome: " + ui.nome.getText() +
                        "<br />" + "Rua: " + ui.rua.getText() +
                        "<br />" + "Número: " + ui.numero.getText() +
                        "<br />" + "Complemento: " + ui.complemento.getText() +
                        "<br />" + "Bairro: " + ui.bairro.getText() +
                        "<br />" + "CEP: " + ui.cep.getText() +
                        "<br />" + "Telefone: " + ui.telefone1.getText() +
                        "<br />" + "Celular: " + ui.telefone2.getText() +
                        "<br />" + "Valor total do Pedido: " + CurrencyUtils.format(BigDecimal.valueOf(valorDoPedido)) +
                        "<br />" + "-------------------------------" +
                        "<br />" + "Lista de itens solicitados:" +
                        "<br />" + "Produto: " + nomeDoProduto +
                        "<br />" + "Descrição: " + descricaoDoProduto +
                        "<br />" + "Preço unitário: " + CurrencyUtils.format(BigDecimal.valueOf(precoUnitarioDoProduto)) +
                        "<br />" + "Quantidade :" + quantidadeDoProduto;


                Properties props = new Properties();

                props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
                props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
                props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
                props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
                props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

                session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new Authenticator() {
                    @Override
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication("", "");
                    }
                });

                pdialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "Enviando o pedido para o email...", true);

                RetreiveFeedTask task = new RetreiveFeedTask();
                task.execute();

            }

            class RetreiveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                    try {
                        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
                        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(""));
                        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(rec));
                        message.setSubject(subject);
                        message.setContent(textMessage, "text/html; charset=utf-8");

                        Transport.send(message);
                    } catch (MessagingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return null;
                }

                protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                    pdialog.dismiss();

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pedido enviado com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Nada garante que o e-mail não vá parar no Spam. Tudo depende do software utilizado no servidor que irá receber o e-mail, quantidade de e-mails iguais enviados e diversos outros fatores.*

> Enviar 10 mil e-mails, é algo muito suspeito para os serviços de e-mail.
>   Ou seja, antes do mil, ele vai para spam NÃO IMPORTA O CÓDIGO.

**De acordo com a google:**

- Mensagens por dia - Limite de envio diário* - 2.000 (500 para contas de avaliação)
- Destinatários por mensagem (enviadas via SMTP, POP ou Acesso IMAP) - Endereços nos campos Para, Cc e Cco de um único e-mail* - LIMITE 99

*FONTE:*

https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=pt-BR

Comment: Nada *garante* que o e-mail não vá parar no Spam. Tudo depende do software utilizado no servidor que irá receber o e-mail, quantidade de e-mails iguais enviados e diversos outros fatores.

Comment: Então a melhor forma de resolver isso é criar outras contas no Gmail para administrar esses envios?

Comment: Veja se isto ajuda: http://blog.mailchimp.com/chimpbot-the-api-wrapper-for-android/

Comment: Então Lollipop, vi e revi mas não entendi. 
Não achei uma solução de JMS e SMTP 
Servidores de email tem um limite mesmo de envios.
Agora por exemplo, se você quiser fazer um email marketing, há serviços que você contrata e também existe a tal conta empresarial, que nada mais é que uma conta com envios ilimitados.